# Euler 6 DoF Equation Continuum Modeled-Derivation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I derive the translational equations of motion like the following,
$$\frac{d\vec{P}}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}\int_v \vec{dp_i} = \frac{d}{dt}\int_v \vec{v_i}dm = \frac{d}{dt}\int_v \vec{v_i}\rho_idV$$
Denoting the relative position vector($\vec{r_i}'$) w.r.t body center($\vec{R}$). Then,

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\int_v \frac{d}{dt}(\vec{R} + \vec{r_i}')\rho_idV &= \frac{d}{dt}\int_v \frac{d\vec{R}}{dt}\rho_idV + \frac{d}{dt}\int_v \frac{d\vec{r_i}'}{dt}\rho_idV \\
&= \int_v \frac{d^2\vec{R}}{dt^2}\rho_idV + \frac{d}{dt}\int_v \rho_i(\frac{\partial \vec{r_i}'}{dt} + \omega \times \vec{r_i}')dV\end{align}

I assume $\frac{\partial \vec{r_i}'}{dt}$ is the relative velocity of a particle w.r.t body center and I assume body to be rigid $\implies \frac{\partial \vec{r_i}'}{dt} = 0$.

From here,

\begin{align}\int_v \frac{d^2\vec{R}}{dt^2}\rho_idV +\frac{d}{dt}\int_v \rho_i(\vec{\omega} \times \vec{r_i}')dV &= \int_v \frac{d^2\vec{R}}{dt^2}\rho_idV + \int_v \rho_i\frac{\vec{d\omega}}{dt} \times \vec{r_i}'dV \\&+ \int_v \rho_i \vec{\omega} \times (\frac{\vec{\partial r_i}'}{\partial t} + \vec{\omega} \times \vec{r_i}')dV\end{align}

I know the center of mass implies,

$\int_v \rho_i \vec{r_i}'dV = 0$,

Then,

\begin{align}\int_v \frac{d^2\vec{R}}{dt^2}\rho_idV +& \int_v \rho_i\frac{\vec{d\omega}}{dt} \times \vec{r_i}'dV + \int_v \rho_i \vec{\omega} \times (\frac{\vec{\partial r_i}'}{\partial t} + \vec{\omega} \times \vec{r_i}')dV \\
&= \frac{d^2\vec{R}}{dt^2}\int_v \rho_idV + \frac{\vec{d\omega}}{dt} \times \int_v \rho_i \vec{r_i}'dV 
+ \int_v \rho_i \vec{\omega} \times (\vec{\omega} \times \vec{r_i}')dV \\
&= \frac{d^2\vec{R}}{dt^2}\int_v \rho_idV
+ \int_v \rho_i \vec{\omega} \times (\vec{\omega} \times \vec{r_i}')dV\\
&= \frac{d^2\vec{R}}{dt^2}M
+ \int_v \rho_i \vec{\omega} \times (\vec{\omega} \times \vec{r_i}')dV\end{align}

I can't justify how this last line yields to LHS of this:

$$M(\dot{\vec{v}}_{b/I} + \vec{\omega}_{b/I} \times \vec{v}_{b/I}) = \vec{F_A} + \vec{F_T} + m\vec{g}$$